Anybody experience a case with AWS Waf Captcha where the user successfully passes the captcha but the endpoint still responds with 405?
details:

rate limit rule 100 requests over 5 minutes
track user using source ip
only apply rule to post requests with uri containing certain string.
responds with captcha action and has 300 second immunity time

I tried rendering captcha if the endpoint responded with 405. The user succesfully completes the captcha and I'm expecting the next api call to return 200.
